# How to use "weighted average easing" correctly with variable framerate?

Tags: mathematics, animation, frame-rate

I often use a weighted average for smoothly animating numerical values to a target value, like so:

```
frame(dt) {
    value = ((value*someFactor) + targetValue) / (someFactor+1)
}
```

As you can see `dt` (delta time) is not used at all, so the result is not the same for different framerates. How can `dt` be applied correctly here?

Comment: This problem looks like this one: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80081/frame-rate-independent-friction-on-movement-in-2d-game, where the OP wants to know where to place de time delta in his formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula updates `value` so a constant fraction of the difference from the `value` and the `target` is removed each frame. Let `alpha = 1/(someFactor+1)`. Then we can rewrite updating to the new `value'` as:

```
value' = (1-alpha) * value + alpha * target
```

Then basic algebra says

```
value' - target = (1-alpha) * value + alpha * target - target
value' - target = (1-alpha) * value + (alpha-1) * target
value' - target = (1-alpha) * value - (1-alpha) * target
value' - target = (1-alpha) * (value - target)
```

Let `u` be the difference between value and target, i.e. `u = value - target` and `u' = value' - target`. Thus:

```
u' = (1-alpha) * u
```

Here we have an option; I will pick the one that doesn't involve calculus. We can repeat this process:

```
u'' = (1-alpha) * u' = (1-alpha) (1-alpha) * u
```

We can see the pattern is that after `n` frames, the difference from the target is `(1-alpha)^n * u_initial`. Let's assume that your game runs at some framerate, and you have adjusted it to your liking. Then after `x` seconds, `n = x/dt_nominal` frames will have passed, where `dt_nominal` is the typical dt when you adjusted it (so 16.6ms for 60fps). So now `u` will be `(1-alpha)^(x/dt_nominal) * u_initial`.

The beauty is that this formula is defined for any real `x`, not just ones which make the exponent a natural number. So here we can replace `x=dt` as the duration of a frame, and get `(1-alpha)^(dt/dt_nominal) * u_initial`. But, using some properties of the exponential:

```
(1-alpha)^(dt/dt_nominal) = e^(-dt * ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominal)
```

So now we can write what the difference is after two frames:

```
u'' = exp(-dt2 * ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominial)
    * exp(-dt1 * ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominial) * u_initial
u'' = exp(-(dt1+dt2) * ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominal)
```

Basically, this formula lets us calculate what the value will be at any arbitrary point in the future. We just choose our update rule to calculate the value `dt` seconds in the future. We also got the nice property that our solution is independent of how many frames occur or their duration, because the final value depends only on the sum of the durations, even though we calculate it individually for each frame.

So we can make our update rule:

```
beta = ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominial 
     = ln((someFactor+1)/someFactor)/dt_nominial
amount = exp(-dt * beta)
value = (amount) * value + (1-amount)* target
```

Note that `beta` is a constant. You can figure out what `beta` is for your code, and going forward adjust `beta` directly rather than using `someFactor`. It turns out `beta` is related to the half-life: it is the 1/e-life, instead of the 1/2-life.

**BONUS**

If you assume your frame times are all reasonably small and so is `beta`, then a useful approximation is

```
exp(-dt*beta) ~= 1 - dt * beta
```

Thus your update rule is:

```
beta = ln(1/(1-alpha))/dt_nominial
value = (1 - dt * beta) * value + (dt * beta) * target
```

In the inner loop you therefore avoid a transcendental function. In UI code, use `exp`. If you are moving particles, use the approximation.

Comment: That was... beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're incrementing `someFactor` every frame, yes?

```
someFactor += 0.1f;
```

Why not try incrementing it based on `dt`?

```
someFactor += 0.1f * dt;
```

This concept is reified in Jason Gregory's [*Game Engine Architecture*](http://www.gameenginebook.com/) under Section 7.4. if you're interested in reading into it further.